# Is there a way to set ODBC Connection options in a DSN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor, odbc

My application (a testcase automation tool) does not support calling ODBC's [SQLSetStatmentOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130794.aspx). I need to set the cursor option [SQL_SOPT_SS_CURSOR_OPTIONS to SQL_CO_FFO_AF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131361.aspx). Right now I connect to the server using a connection string (no DSN). I am using [sqlsrv32.dll or Sqlncl10.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131291.aspx).

Is there a way to set the cursor option in a DSN (or other layer) between my tool and the MSSQL server?  The tool handles creating the cursor (or results set) and iterating through the result set in a way that seems to obscure any ability to manage it directly. It does allow for calling SQLSetConnectAttr() but as far as I can tell there's no way to set a cursor option in there.

All of this is an attempt to speed up retrieving data over a remote connection. In SQL Management Studio I get comparable response times to the local or remote DB, but in the automation tool the remote queries take hundreds of times longer, probably because it seems to be making a round trip to the sever for every row.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set statement options in the connection string that I know of. In ODBC 1.0 and 2.0 you could make calls to SQLSetConnectOption for statement attributes and they set those attributes in each statement created in that connection but a) that is an old version of the API (although it probably still works) b) you still cannot do it from the DSN. In unixODBC you can set some environment and connection attributes in the DSN but your obviously Windows.

I'm not convinced anyway that you've identified the problem correctly and even if you have, how do you know your app does not use SQLGetData (which is disabled when you set SQL_CO_FFO_AF). Are you sure you've not enabled MARs. Did you try getting an ODBC trace to see what the app is doing?